# left alignment of formulas

Tags: equations, align

I am going to write some equation in an appendix for my report. I just want to set my equation in this part to the left. I used the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
    \begin{flalign*}
    \nonumber \text{‎$‎for‎$‎}‎\quad‎ ‎k=1:n-1 ‎\quad‎ \text{$do‎$‎}&‎‎\\
‎    \nonumber \beta &‎= ‎(1-‎\alpha‎‎^2)‎\beta‎‎ ‎&‎
    \end{flalign*}
```

what is wrong with it? How can i do this?

Comment: Thered are at least 3 errors, but correcting one of them depends on what you want to achieve, which is unclear. Two can be corrected: `\nonumber` is redundant since you use the star version of flalign. Also, you should write `\text{for}` without the pair of `$`.

Comment: Since i use the xepersian package i should write $for$. also i deleted the \nonumber , nothing change. i want to align them to the left, being written from left, but i don't know how

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler (and more correct semantically speaking) to change language in maths environments?

Comment: finally, I want to put them together and use same commands for all

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to have amperands at the beginning of each line. Demo (with only a Latin alphabet, hence no `\text{$…$}`:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}

    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{flalign*}
    & \textbf{‎for‎}‎\quad‎ ‎k=1:n-1 ‎\quad‎ \textbf{do‎}& ‎‎\\
‎ & \beta ‎= ‎(1-‎\alpha‎‎^2)‎\beta‎‎ ‎&
    \end{flalign*}

    \end{document}
```

Result, compiled with xeLaTeX:

[image]

But perhaps you should consider use a package dedicated to typesetting algorithms, such as `algorithm2e`.